# URL amigavel com ancoras

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável, ancora

Gostaria de saber como eu uso o `.htaccess` para fazer *url* amigável com ancora.
Ex:

```
www.meusite.com.br/index.html#servicos
```

ficar:

```
www.meusite.com.br/servicos
```